# Give default datetime object value to pandas.to_datetime()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have some dates in string with different formats that I convert to datetime objects using `to_datetime()`. However, the list of strings also has some garbage values that I want to convert to default date.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

print(df)

       dates
0   2018-02-12
1   2018-03-19
2   12-24-2018
3   garbage
```

I use `errors='coerece'` to avert to throw exception. It produces `NaT`, that I want to convert to a default date 2018-12-31, in my case.

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], errors='coerce')
```

Below result.

```
      dates
0   2018-02-12
1   2018-03-19
2   2018-12-24
3   NaT
```

**Approach:**

I am checking if the given value is a valid datetime or not. If not, put the default datetime object. But for some reason, it produces all default values.

```
df['dates'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(2018,12,31) if x is not dt.datetime else x)
```

**Current Output**

```
     dates
0   2018-12-31
1   2018-12-31
2   2018-12-31
3   2018-12-31
```

**Expected Output:**

```
     dates
0   2018-02-12
1   2018-03-19
2   2018-12-24
3   2018-12-31
```

Is there a way to give a default date to to_datetime() function so that, it won't produce NaT? If not, how do I put default dates afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need adding `fillna` at the end after `pd.to_datetime` call

```
pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], errors='coerce').fillna(pd.to_datetime('2018-12-31'))
Out[217]: 
0   2018-02-12
1   2018-03-19
2   2018-12-24
3   2018-12-31
Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I wonder what is wrong with my .apply() logic? Why NaT is also considered a datetime object?

Comment: @RoboCoder change it to `df['dates'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(2018,12,31) if isinstance(x, datetime.date) else x)`

Comment: I tried that, but it still converts everything to 2018-12-31. Also I checked `type(df['dates'][0])`, which is `pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp`. Shouldn't it be a `datetime` object?

Comment: @RoboCoder I think the logic wrong here `df['dates'].apply(lambda x: x  if isinstance(x, datetime.date) else dt.datetime(2018,12,31))`

Comment: it still gives me the same all default dates. I guess, it is a separate question that I should ask. @Wen